# Does Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio work on CE 6?

Tags: windows-ce, robotics, robotics-studio

I have a DSS service I created (For Microsoft Robotics Studio). I then followed the documentation to make it a compact framework service and created a deployment package. I then deploy it to a CE 6 device...

Does a MSRS service work on CE 6? The documentation talks about CE 5.
What should I see if I run it? I expect to see something simillar to running DSSHost on Windows... but I only see a blank screen so I do not know if the service is running. The documentation states that it does take time the first time (+/- 30 seconds on a EBOX-2300) . I left it for a while but there is still a blank screen!

Should I see something? I also tried to access the service using web browser but no luck. Also, how do I set up the security settings to allow distributed nodes?

---

I haven't yet isolated the problem completely but I have a work-around!!!

I initially tried creating my service using MSRS 2008 (CTP) + Visual Studio 2008 without any sucess!!!

I now did exactly the same using MSRS 1.5 Refresh + Visual Studio 2005 and it is working 100%

I will try and isolate if it is the VS 2008 vs VS 2005 or the MSRS 1.5 vs MSRS 2008

PS. I also tried it on CE 5 and CE 6 and both works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Applications can also run directly on PC-based robots running Windows® Vista, Window® XP, Windows® XP Embedded, **Windows® Embedded CE 6.0** and Windows Mobile® 6, enabling fully autonomous operation.

Taken from [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/b/56b49917-65e8-494a-bb8c-3d49850daac1/microsoft%20robotics%20studio%20(1.5)%20datasheet%20en.pdf) document